# Уникальный индекс по нескольким стобцам в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

> Внимание! Это перевод вопроса [Unique Key constraints for multiple
>   columns in Entity
>   Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18889218/5752652)

Я использую Entity Framework, подход Code First. Есть некоторая сущность:

```
public class Entity
 {
   [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public string EntityId { get; set;}
   public int FirstColumn  { get; set;}
   public int SecondColumn  { get; set;}
 }
```

Я хочу указать, что комбинации `FirstColumn` и `SecondColumn` должны быть уникальными.

**Пример:**

```
Id  FirstColumn  SecondColumn 
1       1              1       = OK
2       2              1       = OK
3       3              3       = OK
5       3              1       = THIS OK 
4       3              3       = Тут ошибка!
```

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18889218/5752652

Answer (score 1):

В версии Entity Framework 6 (начиная с 6.1) вы можете указать аннотацией:

```
[Index("IX_FirstAndSecond", 1, IsUnique = true)]
public int FirstColumn { get; set; }

[Index("IX_FirstAndSecond", 2, IsUnique = true)]
public int SecondColumn { get; set; }
```

Второй параметр атрибута - это определение порядка колонки в индексе.
Больше информации можно найти в [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#IndexMulti).

Также в EF6 вы можете написать [своё собственное расширение HasUniqueIndexAnnotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25779348/5752652) или использовать SQL-выражение прямо в миграции:

```
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(string.Format(
                        @"CREATE UNIQUE INDEX LX_{0} ON {0} ({1})", 
                                 "Entitys", "FirstColumn, SecondColumn"));
```

---

Для EF Core.

В EF core [нет возможности](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49526370/5752652) использовать аннотации для указания уникальных индексов по нескольким полям, только через fluent API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>()
   .HasIndex(p => new {p.FirstColumn , p.SecondColumn}).IsUnique();
}
```

Подробнее на msdn: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/unique-constraints

Comment: В `string.Format` опечатка (в оригинале)? Должно быть `{0} {1} {2}` вместо `{0} {0} {1}`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да, похоже опечатка, только судя по [BOL](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) правильнее `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_{1}_{2} ON {0} ({1}, {2})`