# Уникальные поля EF Core 2.1

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Есть база данных с двумя таблицами: Users и Followers. Для доступам к данным используется EF Core 2.1, модели данных представлены ниже

```
public class Follower
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public User CurrentUser{get;set;}
    public int CurrentUserId{get;set;}
    public User PickedUser{get;set;}
    public int PickedUserId{get;set;}
}    

public class User
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Follower> Following { get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Follower> Followers  {get;set;}
}
```

При создании модели используется следующая конфигурация

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(u => u.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Follower>().HasKey(u => u.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Follower>().HasOne(s=>s.CurrentUser).WithMany(u=>u.Following).HasForeignKey(s=>s.CurrentUserId).HasPrincipalKey(u=>u.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Follower>().HasOne(s=>s.PickedUser).WithMany(u=>u.Followers).HasForeignKey(s=>s.PickedUserId).HasPrincipalKey(u=>u.Id);
}
```

Список подписчиков работает, но с одним нареканием: можно подписаться несколько раз
[image: Подписался два раза]

При попытке сделать поле уникальным через HasIndex() выбрасывается исключение.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Follower>().HasIndex(f => new {f.CurrentUser , f.PickedUser}).IsUnique();
```

Вопрос: Как сделать комбинацию внешних ключей уникальной?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то вы хотите чтобы у пользователя было множество подписок, но чтобы подписка на кого-то конкретного была только одна. Т..е никто не запрещает user = 1 подписаться на 2 и 3, но запрещает подписаться на 2, 3 и ещё раз 2. Верно? Если так - то вам нужно добавить уникальный индекс на два поля, я кстати как раз недавно [переводил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/890442/213987) как это делается.

Comment: @AK Проблема в том, что EF Core генерирует внешние ключи автоматически. Возможно ли задать уникальность комбинации внешних ключей?

Comment: Нет, внешние ключи не умеют в выборочную уникальность. Для той логики, которую вы хотите нужна SQL-сущность 'constraints' ('ограничения'). Конкретно в MS SQL Server ограничения реализованы технически как уникальные индексы. Как конкретно - я привёл ссылку на практически готовое решение. Когда будете делать миграцию - посмотрите внимательно, какие оно вам предлагает построить индексы.