# одни и те же данные в БД, entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Как сделать так , что бы одни и те же данные не записывались в БД

```
public CreateTechnicCommand(string name, string email, int age, string productname, int quantity)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.age = age;

    this.productname = productname;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public void Execute()
{
    using(Technic context = new Technic())
    {
        Customer customer = new Customer() 
        {
            Name = this.name,
            Email = this.email,
            Age = this.age
        };
        Order order = new Order() 
        {
            ProductName = this.productname,
            Quantity = this.quantity,
            Customer = customer
        };
        context.Customers.Add(customer);
        context.Orders.Add(order);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Record is Created");
}
```

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, чтобы в таблице все записи имели уникальные значения емейлов? Наложите индекс (аннотация/атрибут `[Index]`), если ваш вопрос про уникальность не на уровне отдельных полей а на уровне емейл + имя - то вот вам полный дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/890442/213987

Comment: а как это сделать ? если можете подсказать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы имеете ввиду, чтобы в таблице все записи имели уникальные значения емейлов?

Наложите индекс (аннотация/атрибут `[Index(IsUnique = true)]`). Вообще, нужно понимать, что в реляционных базах данных повсеместно этот механизм называется "ограничение" (constraint), а в конкретной СУБД майкрософт ограничение на уникальность (uniqueue constraint) реализуется через индекс (index, uniqueue index).

Просто в классе модели:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Если ваш вопрос про уникальность не на уровне отдельных полей а на уровне емейл + имя - то вот вам полный дубликат: [Уникальный индекс по нескольким стобцам в Entity Framework](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/890442/213987)

Ссылки по теме:

- [MSDN Code First Data Annotations #Index](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations#index)